# Slow subsetting eurostat data with eurostat package

Tags: r, dataframe

I am having some problems with subsetting large datframe from the `eurostat`-package:

```
> library(eurostat)
> my.data <- get_eurostat("namq_10_a10")
Reading cache file C:\Users\jkusar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyeXme9/eurostat/namq_10_a10_date_code_TF.rds
Table  namq_10_a10  read from cache file:  C:\Users\jkusar\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpyeXme9/eurostat/namq_10_a10_date_code_TF.rds
> system.time(my.data[my.data$time=="2017-10-01",])
   user  system elapsed 
  65.91    0.66   68.41 
> system.time(my.data[my.data$na_item=="GDP",])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.09    0.00    0.09
```

Why does it take soooooooo muuuuuuuuuuch time subsetting time variable?

Comment: Can't reproduce. On my PC, they both need approximately the same time.

Comment: The same as @Jaap with me. Vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: Apologies; too many installed packages. Now trying to pin down which one is behind this...